# Why does bash not open a file descriptor while opening a file in Sublime or TextEdit but does when opening it in BBEdit?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I created a file called hello.txt, and did a:

```
open hello.txt
```

The file popped up open in TextEdit.

Then, in a separate shell window, I did:

```
lsof | grep -i hello
```

which returned nothing.

I renamed the file to hello.cpp, and did a:

```
open hello.cpp
```

It popped up open in my default text editor sublime, the lsof again returned nothing.

I now renamed it to hello.log, and opened it again. It opened in the log viewer I use: [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), and this time the lsof returned the FD:

```
lsof | grep -i hello
BBEdit    2153 sgupta   16r     REG                1,2          9 24415936 /Users/sgupta/Desktop/testarea/hello.log
```

Does it create the FD's with some other name maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open command isn't part of bash - I think it's an OSX thing (maybe BSD?).  The question isn't even really about open - it's about how Sublime and TextEdit handle files vs BBEdit.

I was able to verify your results, and am led to believe that TextEdit (and apparently sublime, I don't have it) doesn't hold the file open while you're editing.  I wrote a quick little ruby script ( since it's such a lovely  easy language ) to open a file and hold it open for 10 seconds...

```
File.open "open.txt", "r" do |f|
    sleep 10
end
```

and I noticed *it* showed up in lsof:

```
$ lsof open.txt
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
ruby    6531 dfarrell    5r   REG    1,4       14 7602637 open.txt
```

You may want to consider using `opensnoop` to watch the file opens as they happen on the file in question.  I found best results running `sudo opensnoop | grep TextEdit.*open.txt`.  As we know, it *does* open the file, it apparently reads it into a buffer and then closes the file descriptor again when it's done reading/writing.  FYI, `vim` seems to do the same thing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah you're right, I am on BSD shell.
Thanks for the answer. I tried a 'sudo opensnoop | grep TextEdit.*hello.txt' but it just seems to be thinking forever!

Comment: and you're right again, if I do a 'vim hello.txt', the lsof returns: 'vim       2302 sgupta    4u     REG                1,2       4096 24422113 /Users/sgupta/Desktop/testarea/.hello.txt.swp'. 
So it's more of what the particular application does (vim, bbedit, sublime) rather than what open does.

Comment: Yes, opensnoop is going to wait and watch for open events, printing them to screen when it sees them.  Kill with Ctrl-C.  I think the `lsof` output _may_ show the file open - it's a question of timing.  OF course all the programs _do_ open the file - it's just a question of whether they keep them open after reading content.

Comment: Ah. So I just need to write a really gigantic file and keep the finger ready to hit enter on the lsof command before sublime gets a chance to read the whole file :)

Comment: or use opensnoop :)  That's basically what it does, except it uses the kernel's DTrace interface to be informed when the open happens.

Comment: Sublime has this feature, which is handy because you can open a file, do stuff on it, and mutate the underlying file, such as a log, and sublime will then auto react to the mutations and reload the file.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @DanFarrell's great answer, let me suggest using `lsof` with `-p` and the PID of the process of interest so as to list all files the specified process has currently open.

For instance, to list all files currently open in `Sublime Text 2`, use:

```
lsof -p $(pgrep -lx 'Sublime Text 2' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

Note that option `-x` requires specifying the exact process name.

Comment: Ah very useful. It returns me a ton of stuff, Sublime seems to have opened a lot of FD's for fonts and Frameworks and what not. But it did not return anything for the files that I do have open in Sublime.